# shell utility (wkhtmltopdf) not available in apache tomcat

Tags: java, wkhtmltopdf

I have installed wkhtmltopdf utility and its accessible via mac terminal. But when I'm trying to access it via java code, I get the following error

> Cannot run program "wkhtmltopdf": error=2, No such file or directory

I am using this wrapper of wkhtmltopdf https://github.com/jhonnymertz/java-wkhtmltopdf-wrapper

Same code is perfectly running fine in windows system. So i believe issue is something related to tomcat not able to access the wkhtmltopdf utility.

Here is the code that i am using,

```
Pdf pdf = new Pdf();
pdf.addPage(serverBasePath + "/htmlview", PageType.url);

// Save the PDF
pdf.saveAs(filePath + "\\" + filename);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `java-wkhtmltopdf-wrapper` were the actual program is on the disk. Try this:

```
WrapperConfig wc = new WrapperConfig("C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf.exe");
Pdf pdf = new Pdf(wc);
...
pdf.saveAs(...);
```